# Java: Count every number in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to count the occurrence of every number that appears in the array. I've seen other answers, but I do not understand why my method does not work. I have an Array with random numbers:

```
int[] fält = new int[20]
```

This is what I did:

```
public static String statistik(int[] fält) {
    String poäng[] = new String[20];
    String output = "";

    //Clear out the array:
    for (int i = 0; i < poäng.length; i++) {
        poäng[i] = "";
    }

    //Add a star for each time a number appears
    for (int i = 0; i < fält.length; i++) {
        for (int t = 0; t < fält.length; t++) {
            if (fält[t] == i) {
                poäng[i] += "*";
            }
        }
    }

    //Print it out
    for (int i = 0; i < fält.length; i++) {
        output += (i + 1) + ": " + poäng[i] + "\n";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
    return "";
}
```

Not all numbers get a star and it all ends up weird. Why?

Comment: Dis you tried putting if (fält[t] == fält[i]) ?

Comment: Whilst Java does have support for unicode variable names, I would strongly recommend that you stick to ASCII as this will avoid platform specific encoding problems.

Comment: As to the concrete issue - `fält[t] == i` is wrong. I leave it as an exercise to the you to work out why. I would also note that sorting the array first would give you the possibility to make the code much faster - again I leave how up to you.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Why is it wrong? I failed your exercise.

Comment: @Habbo your need to _learn_ not be spoonfed. Take a pencil and paper and write out exactly what this code does, on each of the `n^2` iterations with an array of size, say, 3. Hint: don't use any numbers less that 3 in your array.

Comment: 'Carlsen had memorized engine-moves far into the middle game against GM Sergej Karjakin when playing white, which I find unfair.' --> perhaps what is meant is like 'Carlsen had memorized engine-moves far into the middle game against GM Sergej Karjakin when playing white, which I find lessens the impact of the victory, due to the victory as possibly seen that it is largely in part to memorisation over skill where as in chess960, it would be purely skill' ? https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/22318/why-isnt-chess960-the-standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line :

```
output += (i + 1) + ": " + poäng[i] + "\n";
```

this will start to print "1 :" BUT you count from 0 that's why the output seems weird.

```
public static String statistik(int[] fält) {
  String poäng[] = new String[fält.length];
  String output = "";

  //Clear out the array:
  for (int i = 0; i < poäng.length; i++) {
      poäng[i] = "";
  }

  //Add a star for each time a number appears
  for (int i = 0; i < fält.length; i++) {
    for (int t = 0; t < fält.length; t++) {
      if (fält[t] == i) {
        poäng[i] += "*";
      }
    }
  }

  //Print it out
  for (int i = 0; i < fält.length; i++) {
    output += i + ": " + poäng[i] + "\n";
  }
  System.out.println(output);
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking `if (fält[t] == i)` please change it to `if (fält[t] == fält[i])`

Answer (score 1):

1)Hi, @Habbo, it is because the flat[] array only consists 0's
2) only in first iteration i value will be 0 and then it never be zero again.

```
if (fält[t] == i) {
     poäng[i] += "*";
  }
```

4)so poäng[i] inside this "i" will only zero and never increases
5) that is why you are having weird result

Answer (score 0):

you should change the output message

from    output += (i + 1) + ": " + poäng[i] + "\n";

to      output += i + ": " + poäng[i] + "\n";

at all i think you could optimize your code
by sort it first this will cost 2 Loops
then loop upon the sorted array like this

```
    int temp= fält[0];
    output = temp + ": *";
    for (int i = 1; i < fält.length; i++) {
        if(fält[i] >temp){
            temp = fält[i];
            output +="\n"+ temp + ": *";
        }
        else{
            output +="*";
        }
    }
```

you will have only 3 Loops In your Code not 4